# How to change ant property location attribute with .properties file

Tags: ant, properties, location

Is it possible to change ant property location attribute with .properties file like 
property value attribute?

ant.xml

```
<property name="images" location="some_location" />
```

ant.properties

```
name=D:\images
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See ant manual [propertyfile](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/propertyfile.html) => there is no attribute called location.
The location attribute from [property task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/property.html) is only a 'special' case of a value, that knows how to deal
 with absolute and relative pathes.
If you need to edit | overwrite existing property values(locations) use either :
ant script task (groovy or groovy task recommended)
or some Ant addon like [Flaka](http://code.google.com/p/flaka) or [Antcontrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/), providing tasks for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring a property within the build file will override the same value imported from a properties file.

The only way to do this is setting the property value on the command-line as follows:

```
ant -Dimages=D:\images
```

Comment: The statement "Declaring a property within the build file will override.." seems a bit misleading. I think you meant that so called userproperties, which are properties passed to ant from jvm via ant -Dfoo=bar -Dkey1=value1 .., are 'stronger' than a property defined within the antscript whether by <property name="foo" value|location="bar"/> or loaded from a propertyfile by <property file=".."/>